# Can I limit a range of cells to a specific set of values?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm creating a table in LibreOffice calc. One of my column is actually a choice among several fixed categories - let's say it's a choice of one of several possible strings.

Can I constrain the set of possible values so that:

1. ... an invalid string will not be accepted?
2. ... a drop-down list will appear to let me select a value?

Comment: I believe you are looking for [data validation](https://libreofficehelp.com/data-validation-using-dropdown-list-libreoffice-calc/)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad: Ooh, yes, I think that will do. Make that an answer?